# How to break from a Python generator with open file handles

Tags: python, generator, break

I'm writing a Python generator which looks like "cat".  My specific use case is for a "grep like" operation.  I want it to be able to break out of the generator if a condition is met:

```
summary={}
for fn in cat("filelist.dat"):
    for line in cat(fn):
        if line.startswith("FOO"):
            summary[fn] = line
            break
```

So when `break` happens, I need the `cat()` generator to finish and close the file handle to `fn`.

I have to read 100k files with 30 GB of total data, and the `FOO` keyword happens in the header region, so it is important in this case that the `cat()` function stops reading the file ASAP.

There are other ways I can solve this problem, but I'm still interested to know how to get an early exit from a generator which has open file handles.  Perhaps Python cleans them up right away and closes them when the generator is garbage collected?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By implementing the [context protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) and the [iterator protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) in the same object, you can write pretty sweet code like this:

```
with cat("/etc/passwd") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if "mail" in line:
            print line.strip()
            break
```

This is a sample implementation, tested with Python 2.5 on a Linux box. It reads the lines of `/etc/passwd` until it finds the one for user `audio`, and then stops:

```
from __future__ import with_statement


class cat(object):

    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def __enter__(self):
        print "[Opening file %s]" % (self.fname,)
        self.file_obj = open(self.fname, "rt")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        print "[Closing file %s]" % (self.fname,)
        self.file_obj.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        line = self.file_obj.next().strip()
        print "[Read: %s]" % (line,)
        return line


def main():
    with cat("/etc/passwd") as lines:
        for line in lines:
            if "mail" in line:
                print line.strip()
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Or even simpler:

```
with open("/etc/passwd", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "mail" in line:
            break
```

File objects implement the iterator protocol (see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)

Answer (score 6):

Generators have a `close` method that raises `GeneratorExit` at the `yield` statement. If you specifically catch this exception, you can run some tear-down code:

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.closing( cat( fn ) ):
    ...
```

and then in `cat`:

```
try:
    ...
except GeneratorExit:
    # close the file
```

---

If you'd like a simpler way to do this (without using the arcane `close` method on generators), just make `cat` take a file-like object instead of a string to open, and handle the file IO yourself:

```
for filename in filenames:
    with open( filename ) as theFile:
        for line in cat( theFile ):
            ...
```

---

However, you basically don't need to worry about any of this, because the garbage collection will handle it all. Still,

> explicit is better than implicit

Answer (score 2):

Please also consider this example:

```
def itertest():
    try:
        for i in xrange(1000):
            print i
            yield i
    finally:
        print 'finally'

x = itertest()

for i in x:
    if i > 2:
        break

print 'del x'
del x

print 'exit'

0
1
2
3
del x
finally
exit
```

It shows that finally is run after the iterator is cleaned up. I think `__del__(self)` is calling `self.close()`, see also here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#generator.close

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be another possibility using try..finally (tested on Python 2.7.6):

```
def gen():
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            print 'yield %i' % i
            yield i
            i += 1
        print 'will never get here'
    finally:
        print 'done'

for i in gen():
    if i > 1:
        print 'break'
        break
    print i
```

Gives me the following printout:

```
yield 0
0
yield 1
1
yield 2
break
done
```

Comment: If you ask me, I would put all cleanup code into the finally clause. I tested this also with izip() and two generators, where the other one yields less elements. However, the code I am just working on is complex and does not hit the finally clause - I am investigating why that is so.